# Function with two given properties.

Tags: number-theory, functions

Let $f$ be a function on the nonnegative integers defined as follows:
$$f(2n) = f(f(n))$$ and $$f(2n + 1) = f(2n) + 1$$
 For what nonnegative integers $k$ (if any) can $f(0)= 2^k$?

Comment: How does that define a function?  What's $f(0)$?

Comment: @lulu The question is can f(0) be equal to any power of two so that the function does not contradict itself any way.

Comment: Not following.  There is no reference to powers of $2$ anywhere in your post.  And any constant function satisfies your two properties, so...what are your asking?

Comment: @lulu constant functions dont follow second property.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that the $+1$ was connected to the second property.    But where do powers of $2$ enter into it?

Comment: @lulu it is 2^k at the end. edited

Comment: We can't have $f(0)=2$ because then $f(1)=3, f(2)=f(f(1))=f(3), f(3)=f(2)+1$.  I tried with $f(0)=4$ but ran out of ideas.

Comment: Nor can $f(0)=2^0=1$ since we'd then have $1=f(0)=f\circ f(0)=f(1)=f(0)+1=2$.

Comment: @RossMillikan the answer is any k dont exist. But how to prove?

Answer (score 3):

If $f(0)=2^k$ then
$$f(0)=f(f(0))=f(2^k)=f(f(2^{k-1}))=\ldots $$
$$=f^{k+1}(1)=f^k(f(1))=f^k(f(0)+1)=f^k(2^k+1)$$
If $k>0$ then this is
$$f^k(2^k)+1=f^k(f(0))+1=f(0)+1$$
which is a contradiction.

I don't know yet if there exists some $f$ with given conditions and $f(0)=1$.

Comment: If $f(0) = 1$, $f(0) = f(f(0)) = f(1)$ contradicts $f(1) = f(0)+1$.